# Link in WebChromeClient does not open safari when using WebViewClient shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Tags: android, webviewclient, webchromeclient, android-webview

I use WebChromeClient for opening a link to news.html on my server, it opens safari and shows the content, ok.

But...

When I implent WebViewClient shouldOverrideUrlLoading to intercept the call when it's link to a .pdf file (use another class for it) the WebChromeClient link to news.html stays in webview and does not open safari anymore...

I am doing something wrong, but what?

*Code snippet: (links are long so I shortened it)*

```
myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

//only to catch url override
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.startsWith("http://www.domain.nl/pdf")){
        Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("url", url);
                i.setClassName("nl.domain.domain", "nl.domain.domain.PdfActivity");
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
                return true ;
                }
                else {
                    return false ;
                }
        }
});

myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
//loading
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.domain.nl/news.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

`return false;` means that the url wasn't handled and it should be opened in the `WebView`. If you want to open the url in an external browser you need to explicitly do it.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.startsWith("http://www.domain.nl/pdf")){
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra("url", url);
            i.setClassName("nl.domain.domain", "nl.domain.domain.PdfActivity");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
            return true ;
        }

        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, clear and usefull. This way all the links are opening in browser except the override pdf ones. But some links can stay in WebChromeClient so I thought about the contruction above. Use WebViewClient only to override but handle the rest in WebChromeClient. But that's not the way I guess...

Comment: can you explain why do you need to use `WebChromeClient`?

Comment: I use also GeoLocation in WebChromeClient.

Answer (score 0):

To open the PDF file url :

add the "http://docs.google.com/viewerembedded=true&url=" string at starting of PDF file url string...

try this it work

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView webView;

    webView = new WebView(this);

    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    if (webUrl.equals(XmlFileUrl.MemberDownloadAppForm)) {
        webUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewerembedded=true&url=" + webUrl;
    }

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl(url);

    setContentView(webView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example that helped me to do something similar [Here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/09/android-webview-example.html)

For geolocation add:

`myWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);`

and :

```
private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

  .........

 @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) 
    {
        // callback.invoke(String origin, boolean allow, boolean remember);              
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
 }
```